# Typo3 Extension: Refresh in Backend without creating the record?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have, what i think is a minor problem, so hopefully this won't casue to much trouble for anyone helping me:

In the Backend i want the user to create records of a specific Model. The form should change depending on a select list which is filled with records of another model. It technically works, i set it up with displayCond conditions and to make it refresh i use the line

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_services']['ctrl']['requestUpdate'] = 'checktype';
```

in my ext_tables.php, but whenever i choose an option in the select list and i get the refresh notification ("This change will affect which fields are available in the form. Would you like to save now in order to refresh the display?") it creates a record upon clicking on OK. But that's obviously not what i want. Is there maybe another way to refresh?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this reload at this position without persisting the record.

One possible solution could be to add for each model type an entry to the new record module. Then an editor could choose there which model to create and it is prefilled automatically with the proper value.